# We have a number of buttons being created on runtime as anonymous objects.Can we add an onlick event on those buttons?

Tags: c#

As the title says i have buttons being created as anonymous objects after an event occurs(the click of another button).What i am trying to do is to make this buttons show a Messagebox when they are being clicked.I can't add this functionality to the buttons and i haven't found anything that solves my problem.Maybe it just can't happen this way.

```
Controls.Add(new Button { Size = new Size(50, 50),
    Location = new Point(40 + i * 60, 100),
    Text = i.ToString(),
    BackColor = c,
    //eventforshowingmessage()
 });`
```

Comment: I don't see any anonymous objects here. The `Click` event is under `Click += eventforshowingmessage`. Your method needs the correct signature; `eventforshowingmessage(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: just for clarification. You have created Buttons without saving them in a variable. But they exist as objects of type : `Button` so they are equipped with everything that a `Button` has. Anonymous objects are declared the following way: `new {...}` there is no data type defined as opposed to your code

Answer (score 2):

You could assign button to variable first, and then register event:

```
   public AddButton()
    {          
        var newButton = new Button { Text = "Button 1" };
        newButton.Click += MyEventListener;
        this.Controls.Add(newButton);            
    }

    private void MyEventListener(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        MessageBox.Show($"{button.Text} says: Hello, world");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a *different syntax*: `Parent` instead of `Controls.Add`:

```
 for (int i ....) { // whatever loop
    ...

    new Button {
      Size = new Size(50, 50),
      Location = new Point(40 + i * 60, 100),
      Text = $"{i}", // May appear more readable than i.ToString()
      BackColor = c, 
      Parent = this, // <- instead of this.Controls.Add
    }.Click += eventforshowingmessage;

    ...
  }
```

**Demo:** For instance, let's create `5` buttons and show up which button has been clicked:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    new Button {
      Size = new Size(50, 50),
      Location = new Point(40 + i * 60, 100),
      Text = $"{i}", 
      BackColor = SystemColors.Control,
      Parent = this, 
    }.Click += (ss, ee) => {
      // Lambda: what shall we do on click
      MessageBox.Show($"{(ss as Control).Text} clicked!");
    };
  }
```